# youtube-dl - Store output in separate file

Tags: web-scraping, jupyter-notebook, youtube-dl

I am new to using youtube-dl. My goal is to download information from full video channels (i.e., all channel videos including their titles, thumbnails, view count, like ratings, upload date, and duration, but *not* the video itself). I manage to download these information using the following code (using Jupyter):

`!youtube-dl -o "%(title)s - %(upload_date)s - %(view_count)s - %(like_count)s - %(duration)s" -a links.txt --write-thumbnail --skip-download`

The links.txt file contains the links for the relevant channels.

Somehow, youtube-dl saves all these information in the title for the thumbnail, so I obtain a .jpg file that is named, for example, "TITLE_ABC - 20191217 - 52556218 - 33 - 93.jpg". I wonder whether there is a way to store these information separately within an own .txt file instead of attaching them to the thumbnail title? Any solution suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try [pafy](https://pypi.org/project/pafy/) to get viewcount, duration, rating, author, thumbnail, keywords etc and then tyr to save all this data in to .txt or .csv file

```
import pafy
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSb1_lHcSsg'
video = pafy.new(url)
video.viewcount, video.title, video.duration, video.length
(4790256, 'REST API concepts and examples', '00:08:53', 533)
```

Please make sure you pip install youtube_dl